# Find and replace specific parts of a link inside a <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm pretty new to the whole RegEx genre of code and I need a bit of help.

I am developing a dynamic charting system and reference monthly data up to 6 years back. I have links to switch between years and months. When that link is clicked, it updates the chart (working perfectly) and it updates the table data below (working perfectly).

**Problem:**
After updating the table data, I need to update all of the industry drill down links to the proper year and month, preferably using jQuery.

**HTML:**

```
<td><a href="ind.jsp?year=2012&amp;industrycode=01&amp;month=01">Power</a></td>
```

The link is in the 1st column of the table and there are 12 rows with links that need the year and month updated.

**Desired Result:**
User clicks May of 2010.
The link goes from this:

```
<td><a href="ind.jsp?year=2012&amp;industrycode=01&amp;month=01">Power</a></td><br>
```

to this:

```
<td><a href="ind.jsp?year=2010&amp;industrycode=01&amp;month=05">Power</a></td>
```

Comment: Why don't you just store the format of the string and plug in the number and replace the whole link?

Comment: because the industry codes are different in every row and are not all formatted the same. some include letters as well as numbers, so i cannot sequentially add to the industry code (01, 02, 03, etc..), the conditional function would get lengthly and i figured it would be easier to get the `href` value string, search for specific parameters, and replace the `href` value with the new string

Comment: How do you figure out the month is 05 after clicking? If that is easily done, then you won't need regex to do the replacement.

Comment: This looks like a job for a form that you submit rather than static links that are updated by clicking on (form controls?)

Comment: @nhahtdh - It sends the month variable through a function: `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getCSV('2010', '05')">May</a>`
@James - i need the page to stay static with out refreshing/reloading the page. just reload new data

Comment: just updated my answer to reflect your latest comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should replace the href attribute of all the `<a>`s inside the first `<td>`s of all the `<tr>`s with the new years and months:

```
function getCSV(newYear, newMonth) {
    $("#stat_table tbody td a").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href").replace(/year=/[0-9]{4},"year="+newYear).replace(/month=/[0-9]{2},"month="+newMonth));
    });
}
```

Comment: this looks like the solution im looking for. i modified the script to include my variables `y` and `m` as well as added your missing closing parenthesis: `$("td:first-child a").attr("href", $(this).attr("href").replace(/year=/[0-9]{4},"year="+y).replace(/month=/[0-9]{2},"month="+m));` however im getting an error in the console: `Unexpected Number` any idea why?

Comment: took a bit to figure it out, but i got it! thanks Batman for the jump start. here is what i ended up using:

`$("#stat_table tbody td a").attr("href", $("#stat_table tbody td a").attr("href").replace(/year\=\d{4}/,"year="+y).replace(/month\=\d{2}/, "month="+m));`

Comment: edited the answer a bit, added the id of the table and I also changed it so it `.each`-es through the anchors, so `$(this)` means something ;). If your code copies the first anchor href into all the rest you can try changing to that version.

Comment: awesome. i ended up doing the same thing once i realized that the code copies the 1st anchor href. thanks again Batman!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a','td:first').attr('href',$('a','td:first').attr('href').replace('year=2012','year=2010').replace('month=01','month=05'))
```

​